# Group coordinator lookup failed: The coordinator is not available

Tags: apache-kafka, zipkin

i use zipkin with kafka

```
zipkin.collector.kafka.bootstrap-servers: 172.16.5.147:9092,172.16.5.146:9092,172.16.5.145:9092
```

and work log:

```
2018-10-12 11:32:27.005 DEBUG 20073 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=zipkin] Sending FindCoordinator request to broker 172.16.5.146:9092 (id: 999 rack: null)
2018-10-12 11:32:27.005 DEBUG 20073 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=zipkin] Recorded API versions for node 998: (Produce(0): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], Fetch(1): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Metadata(3): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 [usable: 0], StopReplica(5): 0 [usable: 0], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], ControlledShutdown(7): 1 [usable: 1], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ListGroups(16): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], SaslHandshake(17): 0 [usable: 0], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DeleteRecords(21): 0 [usable: 0], InitProducerId(22): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 [usable: 0], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 [usable: 0], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 [usable: 0], EndTxn(26): 0 [usable: 0], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 [usable: 0], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeAcls(29): 0 [usable: 0], CreateAcls(30): 0 [usable: 0], DeleteAcls(31): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 [usable: 0], AlterConfigs(33): 0 [usable: 0], AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): UNSUPPORTED, DescribeLogDirs(35): UNSUPPORTED, SaslAuthenticate(36): UNSUPPORTED, CreatePartitions(37): UNSUPPORTED)
2018-10-12 11:32:27.006 DEBUG 20073 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=zipkin] Received FindCoordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1539315147006, latencyMs=1, disconnected=false, requestHeader=RequestHeader(apiKey=FIND_COORDINATOR, apiVersion=1, clientId=consumer-1, correlationId=9), responseBody=FindCoordinatorResponse(throttleTimeMs=0, errorMessage='null', error=COORDINATOR_NOT_AVAILABLE, node=:-1 (id: -1 rack: null)))
2018-10-12 11:32:27.006 DEBUG 20073 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=zipkin] Group coordinator lookup failed: The coordinator is not available.
2018-10-12 11:32:27.006 DEBUG 20073 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=zipkin] Coordinator discovery failed, refreshing metadata
2018-10-12 11:32:27.104 DEBUG 20073 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=zipkin] Sending metadata request (type=MetadataRequest, topics=zipkin) to node 172.16.5.146:9092 (id: 999 rack: null)
2018-10-12 11:32:27.104 DEBUG 20073 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient                    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=zipkin] Using older server API v4 to send METADATA {topics=[zipkin],allow_auto_topic_creation=true} with correlation id 10 to node 999
2018-10-12 11:32:27.106 DEBUG 20073 --- [pool-5-thread-1] o.a.k.c.Metadata                         : Updated cluster metadata version 4 to Cluster(id = ywLcZa2hRTCECJAdzcgMKg, nodes = [172.16.5.146:9092 (id: 999 rack: null), 172.16.5.145:9092 (id: 998 rack: null), 172.16.5.147:9092 (id: 1000 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = zipkin, partition = 5, leader = 999, replicas = [999,998,1000], isr = [999,998,1000], offlineReplicas = []), Partition(topic = zipkin, partition = 0, leader = none, replicas = [1000,998,999], isr = [], offlineReplicas = []), Partition(topic = zipkin, partition = 1, leader = 998, replicas = [998,999,1000], isr = [998,999,1000], offlineReplicas = []), Partition(topic = zipkin, partition = 2, leader = 999, replicas = [999,1000,998], isr = [999,1000,998], offlineReplicas = []), Partition(topic = zipkin, partition = 3, leader = 1000, replicas = [1000,999,998], isr = [1000,999,998], offlineReplicas = []), Partition(topic = zipkin, partition = 4, leader = 998, replicas = [998,1000,999], isr = [998,1000,999], offlineReplicas = [])])
```

and loop log...
Can anyone tell me what is the reason?

kafka-server: 0.11.0
kafka-client: 1.0.1
zipkin: 2.10.4

Comment: Looks like partition 0 has no leader and the ISR list is empty. Might be a sign of other issues in the cluster

Comment: But my kafka cluster has no problem, other application queues can send and receive messages normally.

Comment: Can you please show a description of the zipkin topic?

Comment: It is indeed a cluster problem. There is a problem with the __consumer_offsets topic data of kafka. It is good to restart kafka after deleting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a cluster problem. There is a problem with the `__consumer_offsets` topic data of kafka. It is good to restart kafka after deleting.